# Angular Universal in production with Node Express

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I'm trying to deploy an Angular app using Angular universal with Node and Express in the backend.
It worked fine without angular universal, but now I encounter several issues.
Should I simply have a server.ts file, and get rid of the server.js file in the backend since they do exactly the same thing?
The app loads fine initially, but when I try to login, CORS issues arise.
Should I be setting up headers in the server.ts file?/n
Also, the environment variables used are the dev ones, despite adding the file replacement accordingly in the angular.json file.
I've run a build:ssr, moved the app in the backend folder, as well as the main.js instantiated by the build in a dist folder. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

angular.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "mean-app": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "app",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "sass"
                }
            },
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "backend/mean-app/browser",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/sass/styles.sass",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                            "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/js/all.js",
                            "src/sass/my-themes.sass"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/index.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
                            "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/js/all.js"
                        ],
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "node_modules/",
                                "./src/sass"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                "type": "initial",
                                "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                "maximumError": "15mb"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "mean-app:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "mean-app:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "mean-app:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                            "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
                            "src/styles.sass"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.server.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "server": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/mean-app/server",
                        "main": "server.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "src/",
                                "src/sass",
                                "src/sass/styles.sass",
                                "node_modules"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "outputHashing": "media",
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "optimization": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve-ssr": {
                    "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "mean-app:build",
                        "serverTarget": "mean-app:server",
                        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                            "includePaths": [
                                "src/sass/styles.sass",
                                "node_modules"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "mean-app:build:production",
                            "serverTarget": "mean-app:server:production",
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "prerender": {
                    "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "mean-app:build:production",
                        "serverTarget": "mean-app:server:production",
                        "routes": [
                            "/"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mean-app-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "mean-app:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "mean-app:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "mean-app"
}
```

server.ts:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
    const server = express();
    const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'backend/mean-app/browser');
    const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

    // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
    server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    }));

    server.set('view engine', 'html');
    server.set('views', distFolder);

    // Example Express Rest API endpoints
    // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
    // Serve static files from /browser
    server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
        maxAge: '1y'
    }));

    // All regular routes use the Universal engine
    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
    });

    return server;
}

function run(): void {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

    // Start up the Node server
    const server = app();
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
    run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
require('./db/mongoose');
const app = express();
const postsRoutes = require('./routers/posts');
const userRoutes = require('./routers/user');
const groupsRoutes = require('./routers/group');
const topicsRoutes = require('./routers/topics');
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "mean-app/browser")));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "Origin, X-Request-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
});

app.use('/api/posts', postsRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/groups', groupsRoutes);
app.use('/api/topics', topicsRoutes);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "mean-app/browser", "index.html"));
});

module.exports = app;
```

server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const debug = require('debug')("node-kit");
const app = require('./app');
const { socket } = require('./socket');

const normalizePort = val => {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (isNaN(port)) {
        return val;
    }
    if (port >= 0) {
        return port;
    }
    return false;
};

const onError = error => {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error
    }
    const bind = typeof addr === "string" ? "pipe" + addr : "port" + port;
    switch (error.code) {
        case "EACCES":
            console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case "EADDRINUSE":
            console.error(bind + " is already in use");
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
};

const onListening = () => {
    const addr = server.address();
    const bind = typeof addr === "string" ? "pipe" + addr : "port" + port;
    debug("Listening on " + bind);
};

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
socket(server);

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server server.js running on port...' + port);
});
```

Comment: You can use `server.js` to serve your front angular app with universal and have the API in a separate nodejs process. CORS headers should be set on your API and it seems that you've already done it, so it should work. What's the cors error?

Comment: here's the error:
disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/users/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
which means that my production env variables are not being used.
So should I move the code from server.ts to server.js? And only have one server file to start a node server?

Comment: You need to find out the exact reason (missing cors header? Invalid return code?) If you implement cors correctly there is no reason why it should not work the way you have it. And cors is implemented when code is executed client side, so you should have the same issue whether you are using angular universal or not

Comment: I believe the issue is that the server.js and app.js are not being used. Angular universal starts up an express server through the server.ts file. I'm not sure how to tell angular to use server.js instead...

Comment: `Server.ts` is compiled to a `main.js` file, located in `dist/projectName/server` by default, which will run on port 4000 by default. This is used to run the node js process in charge of rendering the page. Running you own version of server.js for the API part on port 3000 is your responsibility

Comment: Yep, i know server.ts compiles to main.js, but I don't need to run 2 servers. I've moved app.js and server.js content into server.ts, as that's what will start up the server. But now I get the following error:
Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'

Comment: after moving content to server.ts, sorted socket io issue, adding type="text/javascript" to the index.html to avoid mime type errors, I redeployed, but some bloody reason, request are still made to localhost:3000... I've obviously added config vars to heroku, but it looks like the production environments variables are not used...
So I'm still getting those CORS errors (despite setting headers correctly in server.ts):
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/api/users/login.